# How do you write, "one who does good" in Classical Chinese?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, classical-chinese

This is a practice from Rouzer Paul's book. It says,

> PRACTICE: Put the following into literary Chinese:
>
> 1. One who does good leads the heart (away) from disaster.

I think the predicate is ... 導心於禍, but what should the subject be? 聖人 seems appropriate, but it seems like that means "wise person" rather than describing someone who does good. Otherwise, 福 means good, but I don't think 福者 makes any sense.

Comment: It's looks a little bit like "善有善報(，惡有惡報)", someone who does good(things?) will get good result?
Or something like "好心有好報" (Someone who have benevolence would get good in return?)
好人、善人?

Comment: Oh, it's probably “善者導心欲禍”, thanks for the memory jog.

Comment: "欲" have a little "becomes, will be" meaning, in fact, I'm not really understand what is "導心欲禍", I didn't see it before... but the “one who does good” could be "善者" right.

Comment: You are confused 卻 (repel) with 欲 (desire)

Comment: 君子 (gentleman) is the most common literary team for decent, honorable, kind, and good person in general

Comment: 爲善者導心於禍 is probably what was intended.

Comment: This is a textbook pattern, you should be looking at earlier lessons to figure out what the pattern is. @AlexanderZ. please post that as an answer.

Comment: BTW, 導心於禍 means "leads the heart *into* disaster". I suppose it's the contrary of what you wanted to say.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would depend on context. What would "from" be then? 自 or 从 or something else?

Answer (score 1):

> *PRACTICE: Put the following into literary Chinese:*

> *One who does good leads the heart (away) from disaster.*

My answer is: 君子修心遠禍

君子(good person) 修心(educates oneself) 離禍 (to get away from
disaster)

You can replace 君子 with 善者; 遠禍 with 避禍  or 離禍

Answer (score 0):

since “classical chinese” is specified, i would recommend:

**積善離殃**

夫**積**者，accumulate 也；**善**者，goodness 也

**離**者，leave 也， go away 也；**殃**者，禍也，disaster 也

> but what should the subject be?

in classical chinese, subject of verb is rarely mentioned; most of the time, if not all, it’s assumed.

have fun :)